# MySQL não conectando conecta por erro em socket

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, ubuntu

Boa tarde amigos, após ter instalado corretamente o MySQL 5.7 no meu Ubuntu 16.04, ao tentar conectar ao banco, recebo uma mensagem de erro falando que não foi possível conectar através do socket.

Executo: `mysql -u root -p`

E logo em seguida, recebo o erro:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

No diretório `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` não existe o arquivo com extensão `.sock`

Já desinstalei e instalei, tentei com a versão 5.6 e nada tem funcionado. Alguma sugestão?
Obrigado!

Comment: No my.cnf você pode editar a opção do .sock, salvo engano. Depois disso use o `chmod -R 755` no diretorio, exemplo: `chmod -R 755 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme [essa resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15039113/664577), um problema comum que causa o `ERROR 2002` é instalar o `mysql-client` ao invés do `mysql-server`.

No ubuntu você pode instalar o pacote `mysql-server` com:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

Outra possibilidade é que o serviço do mysql não tenha sido inicializado. Em versões recentes do Ubuntu você pode fazer isso com:

```
sudo start mysql
```

Finalmente é possível que seu `mysql` não esteja escutando na combinação de endereço / porta padrão (`127.0.0.1:3306`). Nesse caso você tem duas opções:

1. [Editar suas configurações](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12833455/664577) no arquivo `my.cnf`
2. Especificar o endereço e porta esperados na hora de conectar:

   ```
   mysql -h [ip/host] -P [porta] -u root -p [database]
   ```

Answer (score -2):

Ola! tive um problema parecido com este

> "ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"

então eu comentei a linha `sock=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` em `/etc/asterisk/cdr_mysql.conf` e resolveu.